# Prove $[(0,2)]\neq [(1,1)]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am working on this question

> For points $(a, b)$, $(c, d) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ define $(a, b) \simeq (c, d)$ to mean that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$, show $[(0,2)]\neq [(1,1)]$ .

**Proof:**

Let $(a,b) \in [(0,2)]$ and $(c,d) \in [(1,1)]$

Case 1: show $[(0,2)] \subsetneq [(1,1)]$

Since $(a,b)\in [(0,2)]$, we have $(a,b)\simeq (0,2)$, then we get $a^2+b^2=0^2+2^2=4$.

Because $(a, b) \simeq (c, d)$, we can get $(a, b) \simeq (1,1 )$ by transitivity and $a^2+b^2=1^2+1^2=2$. We get $4\neq 2$ which is implies $(a,b) \notin [(1,1)]$, thus $[(0,2)] \subsetneq [(1,1)]$.

Case 2: show $[(1,1)] \subsetneq [(0,2)]$

Since $(c,d)\in [(1,1)]$, we have $(c,d)\simeq (1,1)$, then we get $a^2+b^2=1^2+1^2=2$.

Because $(a, b) \simeq (c, d)$, we can get $(c, d) \simeq (0,2 )$ by transitivity and $a^2+b^2=0^2+2^2=4$. We get $4\neq 2$ which is implies $(c,d) \notin [(0,2)]$, thus $[(1,1)] \subsetneq [(0,2)]$.

Therefore, $[(0,2)]\neq [(1,1)]$ $\square$

I think I am repeating the same argument, but I am not my proof valid or not? If not, can anyone give me a hit or suggestion to write a better proof?

Thanks

Comment: You used the phrase "because $(a,b)\simeq (c,d)$", however there is no reason to believe that is true (in fact it is not as the proof shows).  If you would like to keep that line in there, then you should phrase the proof as a proof by contradiction or contrapositive by beginning with the line "*Suppose to the contrary that $(a,b)\in [(0,2)]$, $(c,d)\in [(1,1)]$ and that $(a,b)\simeq (c,d)$.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a general property of equivalence classes that $[a]=[b]$ exactly when $a\mathrel{R}b$.

So the only thing you need to prove to conclude that $[(0,2)]\neq[(1,1)]$ is that $(0,2)\not\simeq(1,1)$, which by definition is the same as $0^2+2^2\neq 1^2+1^2$. Explicit computation shows this to be true.

---

If the general property is not available to you, you can still get through easier than what you're doing. Namely two sets are different whenever you can find something that is in one but not the other.

We have $(0,2)\in[(0,2)]$ because $0^2+2^2=0^2+2^2$.

On the other hand $(0,2)\notin[(1,1)]$ because $0^2+2^2\neq 1^2+1^2$.

Thus $(0,2)$ is a concrete example of an element that is in one set but not in the other, so the sets are different.

---

What you're doing seems to an attempt to use the proof skeleton for showing that two sets *are* identical, which does call for splitting into $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$ parts and arguing about *arbitrary* elements of the two sets. But proving that sets are *different* is fundamentally different from proving they are *the same*, so the proof skeleton you're following here doesn't make sense in the context.

(Also note that the negation of $A\subseteq B$ is not $A\subsetneq B$, but $A\not\subseteq B$. The way to prove $A\not\subseteq B$ is to show an example of something that is an element of $A$ but not an element of $B$. But what your attempted argument would *actually* prove (if you got the phrasing right) is neither $A\subsetneq B$ nor $A\not\subseteq B$ but that $A$ and $B$ are *disjoint*. This is not what you want -- it doesn't even imply $A\not\subseteq B$, because $\varnothing$ and $B$ are disjoint but $\varnothing\subseteq B$ for all $B$.)